# possible to enable "gumdrop" buttons (close/minimize/zoom) in all windows (disable auto-hide of these buttons for non active window)?

Tags: mac, finder, ui

I often want to use these on non-active windows and of course they're not visible until you hover over them or activate the window, which prevents instant tracking of their location. I don't think they would be distracting if they were visible on all windows, and I have a feeling there is some tweak somewhere that would disable the auto-hide feature. Has anyone ever done this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you're asking for is not possible.  There's no "tweak" to remove the "auto hide feature" because it's not a feature; it's a [design element of macOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/window-anatomy/).

Apple provides very specific guidance when working with the Title Bar within the Frame in their guidelines in [Window Anatomy](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/window-anatomy/) of their [Human Interface Guidelines for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/):

[image]

[image]

This is how users interact with the system and specifically, this is how they *know* what window is active or not.  Apple goes out of their way to document how users should interact with every element; their not going to supply a way to circumvent it.  For context, this can't be done in any OS GUI that I can think of ranging from Windows to GNOME, KDE, XFCE, etc.  There's no reason for Apple to deviate from this standard.